# How to enable specific sorting on ng zorro table?

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, ng-zorro-antd

i have a [Ng Zorro table](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en) with Angular and i have setup server sorting. Is there a way to disable `null` sorting on the table UI?

I wuold like to only sort the table `'descending'` and `'ascending'`. Specifically i would like the table UI to only allow sorting two times like in the image below:

Table sorting `ascending`:

[image: table sorting ascending]

Table sorting `descending`

[image: table sorting descending]

But this:

[image: table sorting null] Will return `'null'` in the backend server and i want to remove that functionality from ng zorro

Is it possible to do it in ngZorro table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you can setup the properties:

```
[nzSortOrder]   
     Sort direction 'ascend' | 'descend' | null  
[nzSortDirections] 
     Supported sort order, could be 'ascend', 'descend', null   Array<'ascend' | 'descend' | null>  
     Default ['ascend', 'descend', null]
```

https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en (Sort property)

Comment: Okay, nevermind you rock! It turns out your answer is the right one! Thanks!